# Is it correct to say "...generate the report more efficient, accuracy and objective. "

Tags: adverbs

Is it grammatically correct to say:

"It helps staff to generate the report more efficient, accuracy and objective. "

or it should be changed to

It helps staff to generate the report more efficiently, accurate and objective. 
?

Comment: What is the context? Is it a single report or a report that is done repeatedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your two examples is correct, because they both contain a mixture of adjectives, adverbs and nouns as a single list.

You can make the sentence with **adjectives:**

> It helps the staff to generate a more effective, accurate and objective
>   report.

...or with **adverbs:**

> It helps the staff to generate the report more efficiently, accurately
>   and objectively.

Comment: Ah ha. Thank you.